# Where did Scriabin define his note to color mapping?

Tags: history, composers

I'm searching for the root source of  Alexander Scriabin's note color mapping.

Wikipedia states in: [Clavier à lumières](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clavier_%C3%A0_lumi%C3%A8res)
that it is located in the score of Prometheus: Poem of Fire.

But, but, but in scores found on [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Symphony_No.5,_%27Prometheus,_Poem_of_Fire%27._Op.60_(Scriabin,_Alexander))
Only the second one contains something that may be treated as this mapping. It is described as a reprint of the first edition, although the first PDF that looks like the first edition does not contain such mapping anywhere.

**Is it the root source of Scriabin's note color mapping?** Or is there a more reliable source somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article *Synesthetic Perception: Alexander Scriabin's Color Hearing* by Kenneth Peacock, in *Music Perception: An Interdisciplinary Journal* Vol. 2, No. 4 (Summer, 1985) details the sources. It's on JStor.

It contains a list of Scriabin's (AND Rimsky-Korsakov's) synesthetic perceptions of all the keys. They're shown as major keys. He says Scriabin objected to the terms 'major and minor' in tonality, but that shades  and nuances of colour were associated with modulation and that composite colours were the result of several tonalities being combined.

It also contains C.C. von Gleich's description of the role of the *Tastiera per luce* part (the top stave) in Prometheus and his convincing analysis of precisely how the colours relate to the harmonies.

[Leonid Sabaneyev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonid_Sabaneyev) (or 'Sabaneev'), an authority on Scriabin, had a printed copy of Prometheus, which Scriabin extensively annotated with colour markings in 1913. It was acquired by the Paris Bibliothèque Nationale in 1978.

I think [this search](https://catalogue.bnf.fr/rechercher.do?motRecherche=Sabaneev%2C%20Scriabine&critereRecherche=0&depart=0&facetteModifiee=ok) should have found it there, but perhaps I did something wrong  (Scriabine instead of Skrâbin?!). Or maybe it hasn't been digitized yet.

Comment: Probably this? https://catalogue.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb43274821t

Comment: Well, I did see that. It's Sabaneyev's two-piano arrangement of the piece. I think they would have been looking at the *score*, because only that would have the *light keyboard* part. Not positive though. And it's certainly from the right period.